# Emacs interacting with MS Windows: how to minimize windows

Tags: pdf, emacs, windows, workflow

Title says it: Is there a way to hide MS windows windows from within Emacs?

What I would like to do is create a function to:

1. Hide all windows including Emacs
2. Restore Emacs
3. Restore SumatraPDF (which shows the PDF I'm working on)
4. Show windows side-by-side (windows)

Any ideas?

Comment: This looks off-topic for use: while some TeX-related Emacs questions fit best here, this looks like something for SuperUser. Unless there is a strong reason not to, I will ask about migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). It can manipulate windows and much more.

When you create a script with Authotkey which does what you want then you can call the script from emacs.